# How to use a ternary operator to add a class to an HTML element in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, ejs

I am new to using ejs. I have a menu and I want to highlight the current menu item.
I have tried this:

```
<li class=<% currentMenu == 'dashboard' ? 'active' : ''%>>
    <a href= '/dashboard'>
       <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
       <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

The value of the currentMenu is served by an express router as shown below:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  if (isAuthorised) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
      title: 'Welcome | MW Tracker',
      email, userName, role, menus,
      currentMenu: 'dashboard'
    })
  } else {
    res.render('pages/sign-in', {
      title: 'Sign In | MW Tracker'
    })
  }
});
```

Please how am I suppose to add the class?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to replace the `<% %>` tag with the `<%= %>` tag in order to output the expression value:

```
<li class="<%= currentMenu === 'dashboard' ? 'active' : '' %>">
  <!-- -->
</li>
```

As the [EJS documentation](http://ejs.co/) states, the `<% %>` tags are for control-flow, no output code; whereas the `<%= %>` tags output and interpolate the value into the HTML template.

For example, the `if` statement below uses `<% %>` tags because the statement doesn't need to be outputted into the HTML. Then inside of the condition, the variable is outputted and interpolated into the HTML template by using the `<%= %>` tags: `<%= currentMenu %>`.

```
<% if (currentMenu === 'dashboard') { %>
  <span><%= currentMenu %></span>
<% } %>
```