# How to use a ternary operator inside "include EJS tags"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm struggling to know how to use ternary operator inside include ejs tags.

I'm using node > expressjs and ejs as js files.

```
            <% if (post) { %>
                <%- include('partials/metas', { 
                    pageTitle: post[0].title,
                    pageDescription: post[0].summary,
                    pageImage: post[0].file? post[0].file : 'default.jpg'
                })%>
            <% } %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `<%- %>` tag with the `<%= %>` tag

please take a look at this answer by Josh Crozier which cover what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987535/3264276

Comment: Thanks, I found an issue with my DB result, the previous code was correct, however, using <%= render the result and I lost the view layout