# change css based on js variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I am passing a variable called `editable` from my backend, which holds `true` or `false` as the variable. once it is passed to the front end, i have access to it. I want to do something like this:

```
if ('<%= editable %>' == true) {
 //change the input tag (in css) to be able to be edited.
}
```

i have this code in the `<style>` tag:

```
input {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;  
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Make your CSS use a class that contains the styles you want to apply to your input tag when it should be editable. Then when you render your HTML using your templating engine (which looks like ejs?), use the `editable` flag to determine whether you should add the class or not. That way you don't need to get the client-side JS involved in adding the class, and instead you can add it when rendering your input within your template

Comment: @NickParsons thanks 4 ur response. so how would i add the css then once i determine it by using the `editable` flag?

Comment: Note that `"true" == true` is false. Either remove the quotes or use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @helplessdev The CSS for the editable input would be contained witinh your CSS class that you create, so when an input element gets that CSS class that you created it would get all the styles applied to it. You can add the class (and hence the styles), using the conditional operator (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41987284/5648954)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate everyone's comments. I have figured out a very viable solution for this, hopefully it can help everyone in the future.

```
function test () {
  if ('<%= editable %>' != 'yes') {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for ( var counter = 0; counter < x.length; counter++){
         x.item(counter).readOnly = true
      }
   }
}
```

and then `onload="test()"` in the `body` tag.